# Need proof for a property in Analytic Geometry

Tags: analytic-geometry

When I was taught Vector Calculus, we assumed the following properties of the dot product (without proof):

$$\vec{\mathbf{a}} \cdot \vec{\mathbf{b}} = \vec{\mathbf{b}} \cdot \vec{\mathbf{a}}$$

$$\vec{\mathbf{a}} \cdot (\vec{\mathbf{b}} + \vec{\mathbf{c}}) = \vec{\mathbf{a}} \cdot \vec{\mathbf{b}} + \vec{\mathbf{a}} \cdot \vec{\mathbf{c}}$$

And then derived the following component form of the Dot Product:

$$\vec{\mathbf{a}} \cdot \vec{\mathbf{b}} = a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 + a_3 b_3$$

In G. E. Hay's Vector and Tensor Analysis, this is done in exact reverse order. First, he derives $\vec{\mathbf{a}} \cdot \vec{\mathbf{b}} = a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 + a_3 b_3$ and then proves both the commutativity and the distributivity over vector addition properties of the Dot Product.

For deriving $\vec{\mathbf{a}} \cdot \vec{\mathbf{b}} = a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 + a_3 b_3$, he uses the formula that the cosine of the acute angle between two lines is the sum of the products of corresponding direction cosines of the two lines. He writes nearby: **by a formula of analytic geometry**.

Now, I was taught this formula in analytic geometry. But, the proof used the dot product in component form directly.

So, I want a proof for "cosine of the acute angle between two lines is the sum of the products of corresponding direction cosines of the two lines" that does not involve $\vec{\mathbf{a}} \cdot \vec{\mathbf{b}} = a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 + a_3 b_3$ because without such a proof the proof in G. E. Hay becomes circular reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

Let **a**, **b**, and **c** be any three vectors. We can always resolve **a** and **b** into components in the direction of **c** whose unit vector is **u**. The diagram below shows **a**.**u** + **b**.**u** $= ($ **a** + **b** $)$ **u**.

[image]

If we multiply both sides by the scalar $\lambda$; where **c** $ = \lambda$ **u**, we have

**a.c** + **b.c** = **(a + b)c**.

Added:

In the revised picture, we have
**a** . **u** = |**a**| . |**u**| $\cos \gamma$ = |**a**| $\cos \gamma$ = OH.

Similarly, **b** . **u** = … = |**b**| $\cos \alpha$ = AK = HM;

And, (**a+b**) . **u** = |**a+b**| . $\cos \beta$ = OM = OH + HM

∴ (**a + b**) . **u** =**a** . **u** + **b** . **u**

[image]

Comment: How does the diagram show that a.u+b.u=(a+b).u

Comment: @truth-seek Not at home. Will be back in 2days time.

Comment: @Truth-seek **a.u** = a.u. cos (angle between **a** and **u**) = a. Cos (the angle) = length of the projection of **a** on **u**. Other products should be interpreted similarly.

Comment: @Truth-seek See added.